# Horizontal align not working properly in Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to align the div vertically using position. its works well in all browsers except Internet Explorer. In internet explorer the `.nav-group` aligned left. How can i solve this.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0nqu2gog/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="nav-group">// Content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container
{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-group
{
  display: table;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried margin:0 auto?

Comment: @Amit, Tried no luck.

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0nqu2gog/

Comment: I think if you change `display:table;` to `display:table-cell;` it may work.

Comment: @Amit I have created fiddle demo. Please check it in both browsers

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Position:absolute` and `margin:auto` for the same div where it might not work. so I modified like this: **[Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0nqu2gog/11/)**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav-group {
    display:table;
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    right:0;
}
```

You can use `display:table;` here it don't affect anything..

I tested in IE 10, latest version of firefox and chrome.. Its working fine..

Comment: I need display:table; compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

change the display:table to display:inline.

```
    .nav-group   { display:inline}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0nqu2gog/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you **[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/0nqu2gog/7/)**

css:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display:table;
}
.nav-group {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your are using absolute positioning is affecting your layout. You have options to either change the absolute positioning and use `margin:0 auto`. or change the display you are giving the element.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1p21tqzq/)

Answer (score 0):

change `display:table;` to `display:block;`

OR

removing  `display:table;` work also

**[SEE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g8dyc3sp/)**

```
.nav-group
{
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: The display: table is must.